# Set default date on Datepicker (SAP UI5)

Tags: sapui5

I want to set default date to a date that I pick NOT a current date even you refresh page. Does anyone know how to fix its?

```
 this.getView().getModel("navModel").setProperty("/targetRouteParams", {
                    view: "Overview",
                    date: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: where is your xml definition? What is navModel, is this a JSON model? is moment this lib, why are u using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment. And if not the current date, from where is you desired date coming?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps as one of the approaches. You can set one property with default date in your JSON model.

Controller

```
onInit : function () {
    var oModel = new JSONModel({
        dDefaultDate : new Date()
    });
    this.getView().setModel(oModel, "view");
}
```

View

```
<DatePicker
    id="idDatePicker"
    value="{
        path: 'view>/dDefaultDate',
        type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date'
    }"
    valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
    displayFormat="long" />
```